# MongoDB Atlas : MongoCursorTimeoutException (ERROR): : Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for -1.000000 seconds

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to shift my mongo cluster to mongodb-atlas.
When I am trying to connect to mongoDB, it is making the connection(which I can see from atlas logs and php-mongodb driver), but it throws error instantaneously.

I found following in php-driver logs

```
2018-04-27 02:27:02 :: IO (FINE): getting reply
2018-04-27 02:27:02 :: IO (FINE): getting cursor header
2018-04-27 02:27:02 :: CON (FINE): Setting the stream timeout to -1.000000
2018-04-27 02:27:02 :: MongoCursorTimeoutException (ERROR): <atlashost:port>: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for -1.000000 seconds`
```

And the same code was running fine, when it was connecting to my own  cluster.

Versions and everything else is same. Version : 3.6

I am stuck in debugging, but can't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code to show the flow of connection:

```
final class mongoConnection {
    static function createConnection() {
        $ctx = stream_context_create(array(
            "ssl" => array(
                "verify_peer" => false
            ))
        );
        self::$connection = new MongoClient("mongodb://user:password@host:port/admin&ssl=true",array("replicaSet" => 'replicaNamw'),array("context" => $ctx));
        return self::$connection;
    }
}

function connectMongoDb()
{
    $mongo = mongoConnection::createConnection();
    $m = $mongo->getConnection();
    $db = $m->selectDB('DATABASE');
    return $db;
}

$mongoDb = $this->connectMongoDb();
$collection->find()->sort(array('_id' => -1))->limit(100); //this is one of the line where I am getting error in my application
```

Output of `var_dump(self::$connection)`

```
object(MongoClient)[21]
  public 'connected' => boolean true
  public 'status' => null
  protected 'server' => null
  protected 'persistent' => null
```

Error :

```
 ( ! ) MongoCursorTimeoutException: <host>:<port>: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for -1.000000 seconds in <filename> on line 33
```

Comment: `Read timed out after reading 0 bytes` would seem to indicate connectivity problems. You might check networking configuration where the application is actually hosted ( and this would be off-topic for this site, better for [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com) ). Alternately if you can include a small listing that you believe replicates the issue from another location ( such as where you work, if that is different to where the application is ) after of course verifying that you do have proper connectivity, then there would be something to look at.

Comment: Or if you can at least narrow this down to a section of code where the error consistently appears. But again, preferable in a ["minmal"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) listing specifically "just" reproducing the problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn : I have edited the question to provide more details.